# Heigth a div donde están los options de un select

Tags: html, css

Quisiera saber como definir un heigth para este div para que me salgan todas las tareas (aunque pongo las options dentro de un div, el inspector de elementos no me lo lee):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es este:

```
<div class="uk-margin">
     <label for="tarea"><b>Tarea</b></label>
     <select class="uk-select" id="tarea" name="tarea" onchange="obtenerTarea(this)">
             <div>
                  <option selected disabled>Seleccione una Tarea</option>
                  <?php echo $result; ?>
             </div>
     </select>
 </div>
```

En la variable $result, están los options cargados previamente con PHP, pero eso es caso aparte

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, no te muestra ya todas las tareas?, por otro lado, no puedes colocar un `div` dentro de un `select`, el propio HTML no te lo va a permitir, revisa lo siguiente para que veas mas info del tag [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/select)

Comment: No es modificar el select como tal, si no el div, o el contenedor donde se encuentran las options para que muestre todas, como ves hay un overflow-x

Comment: No, que sin importar si haya 10, 15 o 20 tareas no haya que hacer scroll, que al abrir el select se muestren todas